# Show $\triangle AES$ is equilateral iff $\triangle IKE$ is equilateral....

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

**Question**

Let the $\triangle ABC$ and $D$, $E$, $F$ be the intersection points of the center circle $I$, inscribed in the triangle, with the sides $BC$,$ AC$, $AB$, respectively.  We denote by $K$ the symmetry of $D$ with respect to the center of the inscribed circle.  We denote by $S$ the intersection between $FK$ and $DE$.  Show that the $\triangle AES$ is equilateral if and only if the $\triangle IKE$ is equilateral.

*My Idea*

[image]

I don't know what to do forward. I got stuck with that $60°$ angle. Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: *Hint*: uniqueness

Comment: Please use descriptive titles.

Comment: If we can prove that $\angle FSE=\frac{\angle A}{2}$. Then the circle with $A$ as center, $AE=AF$ as radius will pass through $S$. This implies $AS=AE.$

Comment: Because the OP wants to continue his argument. A new proof does not answer his question.

Comment: @LiKwokKeung Any idea that will lead to the corect answer are good for me. Maybe my idea isnt going anywhere.

Comment: @IonelaBuciu Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prove that $\Delta AES \sim \Delta IKE$ and consequently one is equilateral iff the other is.

But we first need a lemma.

[image]
In the figure, if $AX=AY$ and $\angle XAY = 2 \times \angle XZY$, then $Z$ lies on the circle with $A$ as center, $AX$ as radius. In other words, $AX=AY=AZ.$

Reason: $\mathrm{angle \; at \; center} = 2 \times \mathrm{angle \;  at  \; circumference.}$

Proof that $\Delta AES \sim \Delta IKE$ :
[image]

$(1)$  $I, F, B, D$ are concyclic $\implies \angle KIF=\angle B \implies \angle IDF=\frac{\angle B}{2}$

$(2)$  $I, D, C, E$ are concyclic $\implies \angle EIK=\angle C \implies \angle IDE=\frac{\angle C}{2}$

$(3)$  In $\Delta DFS, \angle FSD=180^{\text o}-90^{\text o}-\frac{\angle B}{2}-\frac{\angle C}{2}=\frac{\angle A}{2}$

$(4)$ Note that $AE=AF$ by tangent property. Hence by our lemma, $AS=AE$.

$(5)$ Thus both $\Delta AES$ and $\Delta IKE$ are isosceles triangles. We are done if we can prove that $\angle AES = \angle IEK$.

$(6)$ By angle in alternate segment, $\angle AEK=\angle EDK=\frac{\angle C}{2}$.

$(7)$ $\therefore \angle AES=90^{\text o}-\frac{\angle C}{2}$.

$(8)$ $\because IE=IK, \angle IEK=\frac{180^{\text o}-\angle KIE}{2}= \frac{180^{\text o}-\angle C}{2}=90^{\text o}-\frac{\angle C}{2}$.

$(9)$ From $(7)$ and $(8)$, we have $\angle AES=\angle IEK$ .

$(10)$ Thus $\Delta AES \sim \Delta IEK$ and one triangle is equilateral iff the other is equilateral.

Comment: Surprise use of a basic lemma, nice. So $\triangle CDE \sim \triangle IEK \sim \triangle AES$ because their angles are $C, 90- C/2, 90- C/2$. Also $AS \parallel BC$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Hint:You showed $\angle AES=60^o$. Extend DK to meet AS or its extension at H.  A perpendicular from A on BC meets it at P. We have:

$\angle EDC=\angle DEC=60^o$

$\Rightarrow \angle ACP= 60^o$

$\Rightarrow \angle PAC=30^o$

Also $\angle SDH=30^o\Rightarrow HS||BC\Rightarrow \angle ASE=60^o$

that is triangle AES is equilateral.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! May you explain me why $HS$ and $BC$ are parallel???

Comment: @lonela buciu, You'r welcome, because they are both perpendicular on BC.